# laravel | How to replace a field in form's request?

Tags: php, laravel, replace, laravel-5.4

I am using laravel 5.4 and I'm trying to replace the imagePath field in my request (renaming the uploaded image).

**explanation:**

when the form is submitted the request field(`request->imagePath`) contains the temporary location of the uploaded image, I am moving that tmp image to a dir while changing its name (`$name`). so now as the `request->imagePath` still has old tmp image location I want to change `request->imagePath` value to have the new location and then create the user.

Like so

```
     if($request->hasFile('imagePath')) 
     {
            $file = Input::file('imagePath');

            $name = $request->name. '-'.$request->mobile_no.'.'.$file->getClientOriginalExtension();

             echo $name."<br>";

            //tried this didn't work
            //$request->imagePath = $name;

            $file->move(public_path().'/images/collectors', $name);

            $request->merge(array('imagePath' => $name));

            echo $request->imagePath."<br>";
     }
```

But Its not working, Here is the output

```
 mahela-7829899075.jpg

 C:\xampp\tmp\php286A.tmp
```

Please Help

Comment: Just use it as a regular array: `$request['imagePath'] = $name`, no?

Comment: @Jean-PhilippeMurray tried that too but its still doesn't change anything

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe `merge()` is the correct method, it will merge the provided array with the existing array in the `ParameterBag`.

However, you're accessing the input variables incorrectly. Try using `$request->input('PARAMETER_NAME')` instead...

Therefore, your code should look like this:

```
if ($request->hasFile('imagePath')) {
    $file = Input::file('imagePath');
    $name = "{$request->input('name')}-{$request->input('mobile_no')}.{$file->getClientOriginalExtension()}";

    $file->move(public_path('/images/collectors'), $name);
    $request->merge(['imagePath' => $name]);

    echo $request->input('imagePath')."<br>";
}
```

Note: You can also pass your path into `public_path()` and it will concatenate it for you.

**References**
Retrieving Input:
https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/requests#retrieving-input
`$request->merge()`: 
https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Http/Request.php#L269
`public_path`:  https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.4/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php#L635

Comment: It printed the right name!! so if I do $user = User::create($request->all()); will the imagePath have the new value in table?

Comment: Yes, it will have the new value. `$request->input()` will return all input, `$request->all()` will return all input and files.